# How to get current prdocut category ID in Virtuemart

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

Does anyone know what is conditional statement to detect a category id?

I need something like this:

`If product is in category ID = 64 show some HTML`

print_r($this->category);

```
TableCategories Object ( [virtuemart_category_id] => 16 [virtuemart_vendor_id] => 1 [category_name] => Chiloți, boxeri, indispensabili [slug] => chiloti-boxeri-indispensabili [category_description] => [category_template] => default [category_layout] => 0 [category_product_layout] => 0 [products_per_row] => 0 [ordering] => 3 [shared] => 0 [limit_list_step] => 0 [limit_list_initial] => 0 [metadesc] => [customtitle] => [metakey] => [metarobot] => [metaauthor] => [published] => 1 [_pkey:protected] => virtuemart_category_id [_pkeyForm:protected] => [_obkeys:protected] => Array ( [category_name] => Category in record is missing ! Can't save the record with no Category. [slug] => The given Sef Alias already exists. ) [_unique:protected] => 1 [_unique_name:protected] => Array ( [slug] => The given Sef Alias already exists. ) [_orderingKey:protected] => ordering [_slugAutoName:protected] => category_name [_slugName:protected] => slug [_loggable:protected] => 1 [_xParams:protected] => 0 [_varsToPushParam:protected] => Array ( ) [_translatable] => 1 [_translatableFields:protected] => Array ( [0] => category_name [1] => category_description [2] => metadesc [3] => metakey [4] => customtitle [slug] => slug ) [_langTag:protected] => en_gb [_tbl_lang:protected] => #__virtuemart_categories_en_gb [_updateNulls:protected] => [_tablePreFix] => c. [_tbl:protected] => #__virtuemart_categories [_tbl_key:protected] => virtuemart_category_id [_db:protected] => JFDatabase Object ( [mlTableList] => Array ( [0] => content [1] => modules [2] => menu ) [skipSetRefTables] => [orig_limit] => 0 [orig_offset] => 0 [skipjf] => 0 [translate] => 1 [tableFields:JFDatabase:private] => [profileData] => Array ( [JFDatabase::JFDatabase] => Array ( [total] => 0.0002288818359375 [count] => 1 [start] => Array ( ) ) [interceptDB::loadObjectList] => Array ( [total] => 0.0227241516113281 [count] => 62 [start] => Array ( [0] => 1397209811.22307 [1] => 1397209811.22406 [2] => 1397209811.22585 [3] => 1397209811.22628 [4] => 1397209811.23031 [5] => 1397209811.23254 [6] => 1397209811.24075 [7] => 1397209811.24117 [8] => 1397209811.24466 [9] => 1397209811.24608 [10] => 1397209811.27806 [11] => 1397209811.28038 [12] => 1397209811.28142 [13] => 1397209811.28238 [14] => 1397209811.28439 [15] => 1397209811.28616 [16] => 1397209811.28671 [17] => 1397209811.28773 [18] => 1397209811.28882 [19] => 1397209811.28975 [20] => 1397209811.29121 [21] => 1397209811.29171 [22] => 1397209811.29234 [23] => 1397209811.29328 [24] => 1397209811.29369 [25] => 1397209811.29412 [26] => 1397209811.2953 [27] => 1397209811.29915 [28] => 1397209811.29965 [29] => 1397209811.30009 [30] => 1397209811.30052 [31] => 1397209811.30295 [32] => 1397209811.304 [33] => 1397209811.30527 [34] => 1397209811.3057 [35] => 1397209811.30631 [36] => 1397209811.3067 [37] => 1397209811.30721 [38] => 1397209811.3123 [39] => 1397209811.32571 [40] => 1397209811.32638 [41] => 1397209811.32792 [42] => 1397209811.32891 [43] => 1397209811.32985 [44] => 1397209811.3308 [45] => 1397209811.33191 [46] => 1397209811.33233 [47] => 1397209811.333 [48] => 1397209811.33367 [49] => 1397209811.33744 [50] => 1397209811.33793 [51] => 1397209811.3384 [52] => 1397209811.33884 [53] => 1397209811.33928 [54] => 1397209811.34905 [55] => 1397209811.3519 [56] => 1397209811.35311 [57] => 1397209811.35398 [58] => 1397209811.35685 [59] => 1397209811.35732 ) ) [JFDatabase::getTableName] => Array ( [total] => 0.00406312942504883 [count] => 59 [start] => Array ( ) ) [JFDatabase::setLanguage] => Array ( [total] => 0.000144720077514648 [count] => 2 [start] => Array ( ) ) [JFDatabase::loadResult] => Array ( [total] => 0.000228643417358398 [count] => 13 [start] => Array ( ) ) [JFDatabase::loadAssoc] => Array ( [total] => 0.000162124633789062 [count] => 7 [start] => Array ( ) ) [JFDatabase::loadAssocList] => Array ( [total] => 0.000132083892822266 [count] => 4 [start] => Array ( ) ) [JFDatabase::loadResultArray] => Array ( [total] => 0.000250816345214844 [count] => 14 [start] => Array ( ) ) [JFDatabase::loadRow] => Array ( [total] => 0 [count] => 2 [start] => Array ( [0] => 1397209811.30335 [1] => 1397209811.30605 ) ) ) [name] => mysqli [nameQuote:protected] => ` [nullDate:protected] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [dbMinimum:protected] => 5.0.4 [_database:JDatabase:private] => 7624-magazin [connection:protected] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 1 [host_info] => ns13.host-md.net via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.5.32-MariaDB-log [server_version] => 50532 [stat] => Uptime: 346321 Threads: 6 Questions: 164660555 Slow queries: 35 Opens: 1823800 Flush tables: 293 Open tables: 1024 Queries per second avg: 475.456 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 2168966 [warning_count] => 0 ) [count:protected] => 0 [cursor:protected] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => [field_count] => [lengths] => [num_rows] => [type] => ) [debug:protected] => [limit:protected] => 0 [log:protected] => Array ( ) [offset:protected] => 0 [sql:protected] => SELECT `virtuemart_vendor_id` FROM `#__virtuemart_vmusers` `au` WHERE `au`.`virtuemart_user_id`="687" AND `au`.`user_is_vendor` = "1" [tablePrefix:protected] => l50ti_ [utf:protected] => 1 [errorNum:protected] => 0 [errorMsg:protected] => [hasQuoted:protected] => [quoted:protected] => Array ( ) ) [_trackAssets:protected] => [_rules:protected] => [_locked:protected] => [_errors:protected] => Array ( ) [created_on] => 2014-03-16 21:10:24 [created_by] => 685 [modified_on] => 2014-04-08 13:29:22 [modified_by] => 685 [virtuemart_media_id] => Array ( ) [haschildren] => [children] => Array ( ) [productcount] => 6 [parents] => [images] => Array ( [0] => VmMediaHandler Object ( [media_attributes] => 0 [setRole] => [file_name] => [file_extension] => [virtuemart_media_id] => 0 [_foldersToTest:VmMediaHandler:private] => Array ( [0] => /var/www/vhosts/7624/domains/maicom.md/public_html/images/stories/virtuemart/category/ [1] => /var/www/vhosts/7624/domains/maicom.md/public_html/images/stories/virtuemart/category/resized/ ) [_actions:VmMediaHandler:private] => Array ( ) [_mLocation:VmMediaHandler:private] => Array ( ) [_hidden:VmMediaHandler:private] => Array ( ) [theme_url] => http://maicom.md/components/com_virtuemart/ [virtuemart_vendor_id] => 0 [file_title] => [file_description] => [file_meta] => [file_mimetype] => [file_type] => categories [file_url] => images/stories/virtuemart/category/ [file_url_thumb] => [published] => 0 [file_is_downloadable] => 0 [file_is_forSale] => 0 [file_is_product_image] => 0 [shared] => 0 [file_params] => 0 [file_lang] => [_translatable] => [_tablePreFix] => [created_on] => [created_by] => 0 [modified_on] => [modified_by] => 0 [file_url_folder] => images/stories/virtuemart/category/ [file_path_folder] => images/stories/virtuemart/category/ [file_url_folder_thumb] => images/stories/virtuemart/category/resized/ [media_role] => file_is_displayable ) ) [file_url_thumb] => [file_url] => images/stories/virtuemart/category/ ) </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying so far ?

did you need it in details page ?

if yes then try following method. I assume you are in any of the product details page layout.

```
if($this->product->virtuemart_category_id == 64){

   echo 'your Custom HTML';
}
else{
 //nothing
}
```

Also you need to get more details about current product just use.

```
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($this->product);
```

Hope its works..

Comment: what can we do in case we have multiple categories? 
I set one product in multiple categories and one of this categories is SALES I would like to check if it is in this category add a class to product in order to set a sale label in CSS, it see only one of categories unfortunately

Comment: Did you check the entire product array ? or print_r($this->category); will help.

Comment: I added 'print_r($this->category);' result, unfortunately i is in got only one category id

Comment: check you new question